# Can input matrices also be used to store the output matrix with CUBLAS?

Tags: c, cuda, gpgpu, cublas

For instance, [`cublas<t>geam()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#topic_9_1) will do:

[image: C = αop(A) + βop(B)]

**But what if I want to store the result in `A` anyway**? Can I call it with pointers `*C = *A` so that:

[image: A = αop(A) + βop(B)]

without fear that I may be writing output to a matrix still being read as an input??

If so, are guaranteed that we do this with all other CUBLAS matrix operations safely?

Comment: For this particular operation I would think it is OK if both the OPs are N (i.e. you are not performing a transpose). But as hubs says, the documentation says the behavior will be undefined. So it is best to err on the side of safety and use the extra space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is alright in the cublas documentation, as you posted it - [cublasgeam()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#topic_9_1) - `If C overlaps A or B, then behaviour is undefined`.
Nvidia won't guarantee that this will work, if `C == A`.

Comment: Other CUBLAS routines are not not guaranteed to work in-place either.

Comment: @talonmies thanks for that addition. I removed the wrong part from my answer.

Comment: Ahh thanks. I was actually using level 3 version of cublasgemm() and just happened to be using the extension version as an example so I missed that statement - d'oh!